# Is it possible to perform another AJAX call when another AJAX call fails?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to perform another ajax call when a running ajax call fails?

Something like...

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myurl.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: postdata
}).done(function {
    // do some stuff
}).fail(function {
    var faildata = jqXHR.statusText;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'mybackupurl.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: faildata
    }).done({...});
});
```

The idea here is to create a server-side log file (or do a database entry) that can be checked for AJAX calls that have failed. So that the data can be retrieved later on for debugging.

Comment: My answer is yes, you can do another ajax call on success or fail, etc

Comment: Well, that was quick. Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing special about the success and failure functions. They can do anything you want.

Comment: Can they make coffee?

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer: **yes, it is possible**. But…

The way you check for returned promises is a little wrong — it should be `function() {...}` not `function { ... }`. Also, it is good to note what kind of variables are returned by the `.done()` and `.fail()` methods:

- `.done()` returns `data`, `textStatus` and the `jqXHR` object
- `.fail()` returns the `jqXHR` object, `textStatus` and finally the `errorThrown`

The order you name these variables within the function call is important, otherwise you are accessing things that are not what they should be ;)

---

```
$.ajax({

    url: 'myurl.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: postdata

}).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

    // do some stuff

}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'mybackupurl.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: textStatus
    }).done(function() {
        // Do more
    });

});
```

Comment: You pointed the OP in your answer to some syntax error, but its not related to the question.

Comment: @lolka_bolka Still, it should be corrected. Otherwise OP will run into errors if he/she uses the original piece of code. If there is a problem, why not correct it early on?

Comment: @Terry, so noted and your comment is appreciated :-) but the code was just a scribble to hopefully clarify my intentions without paying too much attention to the correctness of the code...and also, I'm dutch. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **Yes!** as stated by Marco Mura